# html5 video not working on ipad

Tags: html, html5-video

I have an html5 video that should work on ipad. Controls must be hide and on user tap on the ipad, the html5 video must play.

I am using html5video.js What I can see on ipad is only the poster image and when I tap the ipad, nothing happens. below is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=768px, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
   <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>

   <script>
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.addEventListener('touchstart',function(){
            video.play();
    },false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="auto" width="620" height="860" poster="img/poster.png" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="video/Motion.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are you serving the video with the correct MIME type? The excellent [Video On The Web](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html) article by Dive Into HTML 5 covers everything you need to know about serving Video. Way down the bottom of the article (past all the encoding help) covers [issues with iPhones and iPads](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#ios) as well as the [need for the correct MIME type](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#video-mime-types). It's well worth the full read.

**EDIT**

To work with iOS the `Accept-Ranges: bytes` HTTP response header must be included, see: [Safari Web Content Guide - Configuring Your Server](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6)

Comment: Just figured it out. onclick will not work on ipad. I used ontouchstart

Comment: Thanks for that hint about the Accept-Ranges header. Was trying to get Videos for a Vaadin application working on iOS for days.

Answer (score 2):

Try this trick (void user to tap screen):

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {

  video.play();

  // They use this first touch/click event for buffering others video.
  // with this trick 

  video2.play();
  video2.pause();

  // After in your program you can call from 'code' play video.
  // Sum of success buffering per one click is 3 ~ 6 ( android or ios ).


}, false);
```

For me works on android tablet samsung , iphone and ipad 2/3.

**Updated :**

With new version of browsers also autoplay is enabled by default, you need to put attribute mute for success.

There is no final solution. For example firefox version 64 on mac don't support but same version on linux support autoplay. And so long...

Answer (score 1):

In my case the MIME type was correct but my server was not allowing the client to request partial files with the Range HTTP header.
So the server must send "Accept-Ranges: bytes" when you request that mp4 file, the iPad will refuse to download that file if it is forced to download it entirely.

Comment: This was my issue. I'm using Flask with 'send_file' and 'send_from_directory' calls. I had to add 'conditional=True' argument to those calls.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The video wasn't playing only on iPad and iPhone4. Nothing worked. Finally I discovered that my .mp4 file was in wrong format. I didn't create that file. After I converted it once again to mp4 format it worked.