# local wordpress installation not playing html5 video

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, video, xampp

I'm developing a WordPress site using XAMPP.  I am using the html5 video tag in the header to display the video.  I have the videos on the C:\ drive - not in the XAMPP installation.  `C:\WebVideo` is the path.

I am testing in the five major browsers:

- Firefox 27.0.1 which says "No video with supported MIME type found"
- IE9 which just displays a big black box.
- Chrome Version 32 displays the control bar as does Opera 17.
- Safari 5.1.7 shows the header without a hint that video is supposed to be displayed.

So, the only clue I have is the MIME types.

I do have an `.htaccess` file located in the `C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress` folder.  This is the content of that file:

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/webm .webm
```

I know the file is being read because when I put a bunch of nonsense in the file I get internal sever errors.  When the nonsense is removed Wordpress functions correctly.

Here is the HTML I am using:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="" preload="" style="width:30%; position:absolute; float:right; ">
<source src="C:/WebVideo/my-vid.mp4"></source>
<source src="C:/WebVideo/my-vid.ogv"></source>
<source src="C:/WebVideo/my-vid.webm"></source>
</video>
```

The video itself is not broken it plays fine.

I've been all over the web for about 2 hours looking for some fix and come up empty handed. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: *sidenote:* `position: absolute` with `float: right`? doesn't sound logical.

Comment: You shouldn't use local path for your video `src`. If you want to be accessed by WordPress (same for other websites), put it under the directory of web root, which is `C:/xampp/htdocs/` in your case.

Comment: @Shivan Hello Shivan. I got to wondering about that the minute I posted, but I didn't know quite how to fix it.  So, now the videos are playing fine -- except for Safari where the video doesn't show up at all. But I guess that another issue...  Thanks very much.

Comment: @Shivan Oh, the style I'm still working on.  This is a WeaverII template and the absolute positioning was the only way I could find to get it into the header.  The float: right is not doing what I thought it would do. The video shows up on the left side. But, I wanted to at least get the video showing up first. Thanks again.

Comment: (Windows only) QuickTime has to be installed in order to make Safari to load video via `video` tag. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad)

Comment: @Shivan Shivan you are a goldmine! Now all browsers are playing the video.  Thank you so very, very much!

Comment: do not use c:/ path add your video on your theme folder add apply your site url to path.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, Safari requires QuickTime to be-installed to playback video via `<video>` tag (Windows only).

Also, it is suggested to provide alternative video source for fallback purpose. Even better, use libraries that has Flash player fallback, such as [videoJS](http://www.videojs.com).