# HTML5 video in Safari not working

Tags: java, html, video, safari

In our **Java EE** application we use the HTML5 `<video>` tags for playing **MP4** videos.
We use JBoss 7 as the application server. Videos are retrieved via Struts2 action like this :  `www.myproject.com/namespace/documents/3/zbRdTKQKLWnA2ZiY61Gx`

where `zbRdTKQKLWnA2ZiY61Gx` is a name of video on the server.

struts.xml :

```
...

<action name="documents/*/*" class="namespace.action.GestionDocumentAction" method="obtain">
    <param name="typeId">{1}</param>
    <param name="identifiantDocument">{2}</param>
    <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">video/mp4</param>
        <param name="inputName">flux</param>
        <param name="allowCaching">true</param>
        <param name="contentDisposition">inline;filename=${filename}</param>
    </result>
</action>

...
```

It works **fine in Chrome and Firefox**, but **not in Safari** on Mac.

In Safari when I open the page containing a `<video>` tag, "Loading" is displayed but it doesn't load the video.

**Here comes the really weird thing**.

If paste the link to a video **directly in the browser**, it plays **correctly**.
Then if I reload the page with the said video, it plays **fine**.

The same thing happens with all videos in the application.

What is happening ? Why are the videos not playing at first?

---

**Dev tools in Safari :**

When I **initially** load the page I get the following result :
[image]

All warnings are for CSS.

For opening the file **directly in browser** for the first time I get :
[image]

The **error** is "Failed to load resource: load handled by the module" :
[image]

When I **reload** the page I get **the same response**, but now I can play the video :
[image]

I think the problem goes from range headers.
Actually I use this one :

```
this.getServletResponse().setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
this.getServletResponse().setHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
this.getServletResponse().setHeader("Content-Length", "383631");      // 383631 - just for exemple, I use a real size
this.getServletResponse().setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes 0-383630/383631"); // 0-383630/383631 - the same
this.getServletResponse().setStatus(206);
```

Comment: Hi @illusion are you using https?

Comment: Hi @r1verside ! No, we use http.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a fiddle with safari? Or is it specific to your enviroment (server)?

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll, it's specific to our environment, we use Struts2. I have updated the question.

Comment: Seems to me a mime-type issue, but might as well be a problem with the stream (that would explain why after caching it plays just fine), but it's hard to tell without having a test environment.

Comment: if you open the dev tools in Safari and look at error console and/or network resources when you initially load the page does anything appear weird? are you seeing the request in the server logs?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal, I answered in my question.

Comment: What happens if your server appends the extension `.mp4` to the resource URL? (and of course, resolves it properly)

Comment: @AaronD, thanks for the idea. It seems to me that it's a right way. I have tried this, but it didn't change the situation. Perhaps, I didn't apply it correctly... but with a direct link in a browser it still works well. Do I need change something else in the code, header, for example?

Comment: There may be other problems. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad) is another list of answers to the same problem - one big one at least for iOS Safari is whether your application supports byte-range requests. [Here](https://gist.github.com/fehmicansaglam/1781977) is a GitHub gist showing one implementation of that.

Comment: @illusion I'm having a similar issue, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 9):

Safari has a problem where if the video resource requested does not specifically have the extension **.mp4**, even if the mime type is correctly set. I could replicate your problem - if the video resource was just a string identifier (without `.mp4`), Safari would display a preview for the video but it wouldn't actually play. When the resource was renamed to `filename.mp4`, Safari started playing the video as expected. Chrome worked fine either way.

If you change your `namespace.action.GestionDocumentAction` class so that when the second parameter ends in `.mp4` it strips off the extension to find the correctly-named local resource, it should be able to return the video with the URL ending in .mp4 as Safari expects - `www.myproject.com/namespace/documents/3/zbRdTKQKLWnA2ZiY61Gx.mp4`.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem but as the only (nice) answer you deserve the bounty.

Comment: For me this actually solved the issue. I was unable to run videos on safari but appending .mp4 solved it.
Maybe it's because i'm using spring boot i don't know.