# HTML video tag Safari

Tags: html, cross-browser, html5-video

I have a website that uses the HTML5 video tag;

```
<video id='video' autoplay muted loop controls>
     <source src="video/homevideo.mp4" />
</video>
```

The video is playing on Firefox and Chrome but not at all in Safari (desktop, iPhone etc). MP4 should be supported and work on Safari.

Comment: Solution for all browsers: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/66344245/3087186](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66344245/3087186) ...

Answer (score 3):

The same problem has already been discussed here: [HTML5 Video tag not working in Safari , iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad#20347545)
Either it has to do with a MimeType issue or the web server does not support HTTP byte-range requests.

Comment: The local server provided by Ember 2.18 is one of these cases. Just pushed the code to a Development server and it all works fine there.