# How to play .MP4 files in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, video, safari, mp4

I have developed a website using wordpress. I have placed a video in the home page and it works fine in Chrome, Mozila and IE but in Safari. I have used the html5 video tag, can any one suggest how I can play MP4 videos in Safari? This is the code I am using to play the video in my site.

```
<video width="800" height="1000" controls>
  <source src="life.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="life.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser doesn't support the video.
</video>
```

The code above worked fine, except in Safari.
Is there any flash player solution toplay .mp4 videos?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video tag not working in Safari , iPhone and iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** You don't need Flash Player plugin just for playing an MP4 file in most browsers. MP4 decoding is already built-in. Use Flash only for un-supported features.

**(2)** WordPress has its own video embedding **[short code](https://codex.wordpress.org/Video_Shortcode)** method, if the video tag method is not working well for you.

Make a new blank post in WP and simply write a shortcode like below. Check it plays in Preview?

```
[ video src = "your_video_file.mp4" ]
```