# Flask mp4 html5 video not working in safari

Tags: python, html, video, flask, html5-video

I am solving strange problem with Flask and HTML5 video. I want to show video in video tag. Video is mp4 with H.264 codec. It is working everywhere except Safari on OSX and safari on IOS. Place with video is blank. When I explore this video through developer tools, safari says unable to load resource. I learnt that it could be related somehow with http headers. So I thought it is because I use default flask developmental server. So I uploaded it on pythonanywhere.com but it is the same. I have video in static folder, my html looks like this:

```
 <div id="reel-vid">
    <video class="img-responsive" id="video1">                              
    <source src="static/img/showreel_video_L2.mp4" type="video/mp4">                                
    Your browser does not support this video.
    </video>
 </div>
```

I tried different resolutions, different formats (webm, ogg). Nothing work. Thank you for help.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad)

Comment: Can you share a link to the video if possible?