# Video tag on safari (iOS) with Flask and GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, html5-video

As per title, I am trying to render a Jinja2 template with an html5  tag using a Flask backend on Google App Engine. It works with no problems of chrome/firefox (windows/android) but no luck on safari for iOS (tested on iphone 7).

```
    <video id="media-video" width="100%" muted controls>
            <source src="{{url_for('static', filename = 'test.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4">
            Not supported
    </video>
```

I have searched and read about it (e.g.
[HTML5 Video tag not working in Safari , iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad#20347545)) but my case seems somehow different ... no errors are displayed but the video does not seem to be loaded (the video is h.264).

Any idea on why?
Are flask/google-app-engine adding complexity to the problem?

Comment: Plug your iPhone into your computer, and enter Developer mode in Safari.  You can debug the browser response on your phone via your computer

Comment: thanks @GAEfan, I just did that. No error but the resource is not loaded and there is no transferred content for it ... can it be related to missing headers ? I tried:
r = make_response(render_template('xxx.html'))
r.headers['Accept-Ranges'] = 'bytes'

Comment: When you inspect the video tag, what is the url?  Is it malformed? And for troubleshooting, add a height tag.

Comment: thanks, I tried both things as well. The url seems OK (relative path), I also tried hardcoding the full path and serving the file from google storage ...

Answer (score 0):

Try a different tag structure:

```
<video id="media-video" 
       width="100%"
       src="{{url_for('static', filename = 'test.mp4')}}" 
       type="video/mp4"
       muted controls
>
</video>
```

Comment: No difference, same behaviour and I can't really see the headers of the request