# HTML 5 Video iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, video

It may seem a dumb question but I cannot figure out a solution, I am embedding a local video using the standard html5 video syntax, the problem is that on safari / ios the video won't play and a quicktime striketrhough icon appears instead.
The same error appears on w3c page if I try to playback a video using iphone / ios (testing on xcode):
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp[image]

How can I fix this problem?
This is the code I am using:

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try adding both `autoplay` and `controls="true"` to the video tag? I know I encountered the same problem when rendering a webrtc stream in a webview, but I've no idea anymore what the issue was.

Comment: just try to add <video  autoplay controls="true"> here is the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad