React video 'not playing the video on mobile browser
  <video autoPlay muted loop>
    <source
      src="https://sdfasdfsdaf"
      type="video/webm"
    />
  </video>

I have this simple code. It starts the video and keeps playing it. However, it doesn't do that on mobile safari. Also, it always enters the full screen mode that I don't want to do that.
How can I make it to play the video on mobile safari and chrome while not making it to become a full screen. Because I want it to be a background video.

to begin try adding the playsinline attribute (it should prevent the fullscreen behaviour). As of the background video feature maybe you meant in terms of z-index: -1? By the way the videoelement can be styled to match the appearence you best prefer. Try also looking here for further suggestions related to the video element on the safari web browser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168709/html-video-not-playing-in-safari-browser

playsinline worked with the z-index. But, Safari is not looping the video. Do you know why?

I posted an answer to better explain the strategy of using the ended event to restart the player when the video finished. It seems overkill but it may circumvent the behaviour you described where Safari doesn't loop the video

As I suggested in my very first comment a solution might be adding the playsinline attribute to the video element to prevent the fullscreen behaviour.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#playsinline

A Boolean attribute indicating that the video is to be played
"inline", that is, within the element's playback area. Note that the
absence of this attribute does not imply that the video will always be
played in fullscreen.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_for_safari#3030250

When you want to display short-form content, it is more optimal to
play your video inline. Use  to play videos inline.
Without the playsinline attribute, videos must be in full-screen mode
for playback on iPhone. If videos do play in full-screen mode, they
will continue to play inline when the user exits full-screen mode,
even if the video element doesn’t contain the playsinline property.

Since you also added later that the looping doesn't occur despite having used the loop attribute, you may try listening to its ended event to trigger the restart of the video from the beginning.
Trying myself using Safari running on an iPhone I see this demo working by pressing the Run code snippet button and toggling it to full screen. The very first strategy using the loop attribute correctly works. The second strategy engaging js doesn't.
If you can't meet the condition to make it work on your device I'm out of clues. I mean maybe it's related to the whole low power argument made on the apple link I shared bevfore. I also observed that toggling the fullscreen or interacting somehow with the page may interrupt the looping feature. So it behaves inconsistently anyway.
I share here another important link talking about New <video> Policies for iOS
https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/
Here's a demo showing both the scenarios:


const myvideo = document.getElementById('myvideo');
myvideo.addEventListener('ended', (event) => {
  event.target.currentTime = 0;
  event.target.play();
});
video{
  z-index: -1;
}
<p>Using the loop attribute</p>

<video autoplay muted loop playsinline width="250">
  <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>

<p>Without using the loop attribute but using the ended event to reset the player</p>

<video id="myvideo" autoplay muted playsinline width="250">
  <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>




:/ It perfectly works on Chrome but not on Safari.

I'm sorry to hear that.. I further looked on the internet for other advices and here https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/709821 someone talked about the low power mode condition.. maybe that's another factor?

no it's not related... I findally tried to open the demo using safari from iphone.. and actually it doesn't loop :( but the first video does! I mean when using the loop attribute it works.. it's the js strategy that doesn't

interesting. I will just try with google. maybe it is my safari but thank you so much!
