# <link rel=preload> must have a valid `as` value

Tags: html, preload

I'm trying to preload a video using the `link` tag's preload rel value per [mdn's documentation on preload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content).

in my index.html file I'm adding the following to the head:

```
<link rel="preload" as="video" type="video/mp4" href="video/2_1.mp4" />
```

In chrome this works fine and preloads the file without issue.

When I open the page in safari 11.3 either on my desktop or on an iphone I get a console error message:

> must have a valid `as` value

According to the ["what types of content can be preloaded"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content#What_types_of_content_can_be_preloaded) section of the documentation that contains the list of valid values I'm definitely using the correct `video` type.

I checked both the [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Browser_compatibility) for mobile safari preload option on the link tag and it shows a "compatibility unknown" question mark. I also checked[caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=preload) and it seems to indicate that as long as my mobile safari version is at 11.3 I should be able to use it.

The phone and my desktop are both at safari 11.3, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Any ideas/insight??

Comment: Does your document have a valid Doctype ?

Comment: Maybe you could tweet or email Yoav Weiss https://webkit.org/status/#specification-preload.

Comment: @UtkarshBais checking

Comment: And interesting, @JamesT. If the doctype isn't the issue I'll shoot a message to Yoav. Thanks both of you :)

Comment: ah, yep we have the HTML5 doctype so that's not it.

Comment: It's not the link tag, but you might want to have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad

Answer (score 8):

it seems webkit disable preload for video and audio file.

```
if (RuntimeEnabledFeatures::sharedFeatures().mediaPreloadingEnabled() && (equalLettersIgnoringASCIICase(as, "video") || equalLettersIgnoringASCIICase(as, "audio")))
    return CachedResource::MediaResource;
if (equalLettersIgnoringASCIICase(as, "font"))
    return CachedResource::FontResource;
#if ENABLE(VIDEO_TRACK)
if (equalLettersIgnoringASCIICase(as, "track"))
    return CachedResource::TextTrackResource;
#endif
return std::nullopt;
```

https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/loader/LinkLoader.cpp#L125

```
auto type = LinkLoader::resourceTypeFromAsAttribute(as);
if (!type) {
    document.addConsoleMessage(MessageSource::Other, MessageLevel::Error, String("<link rel=preload> must have a valid `as` value"));
    return nullptr;
}
```

https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/loader/LinkLoader.cpp#L239-L243

I'm not sure if we can enable mediaPreloadingEnabled on safari by changing some configuration.

Answer (score 2):

### `as="video|audio|document"` isn't supported on Chrome.

Didn't found any official post/bug on the browsers sites, but I did found this on chromium repository:
https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/99314be8152e688bafbbf9a615536bdbb289ea87/third_party/blink/web_tests/fast/dom/HTMLLinkElement/link-preload-unsupported-destination.html

> ```
> <link rel=preload href="resources/empty.html">
> <link rel=preload href="resources/empty.html" as="document">
> <link rel=preload href="../../../media/content/test.mp4" as="audio">
> <link rel=preload href="../../../media/content/test.wav" as="video">
> <!--This test verifies that specific warnings are shown when preload
>    resources use unsupported (but valid) destinations. -->
> ```

Basically it's a test that verify that Chrome throws a warning when using those link unsupported 'as' attributes

Comment: Also getting this error for `as="image/svg+xml"` in latest Chrome.