# Warning: <link rel=preload> must have a valid `as` value

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, preload

When trying to `rel="preload"` a video file using a `<link>` tag in the `<head>` I get a warning in the Chrome console stating:

`` <link rel=preload> must have a valid `as` value ``

My tag is:

`<link rel="preload" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/[myFilePath].mp4" as="video" type="video/mp4" media="(min-width: 768px)" crossorigin>`

Comment: maybe duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593084/link-rel-preload-must-have-a-valid-as-value

might you got some help

Comment: That warning was said to be a bug a while ago, see here [https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/2492].I am just not sure if there was  ever a permanent fix to it. Is this warning present when you use mozilla as well?

Comment: @Lelo I don't get the warning using Firefox. It doesn't seem to preload the video, though.

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully this answer will get outdated soon, but when I look at the official docs, (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link), I find that "preload" has questionable support for both Chrome and Safari.  The warning we are all seeing is likely due to the fact that Chrome/Safari is recognizing the "preload" tag but is not recognizing "audio" (or whatever you are using) as a valid value for the "as" tag.

Regarding the answer saying to replace "preload" with "prefetch", do not do this.  In fact, as a general rule, I would never in any situation assume that two differntly-named tags/variables/anythings are the same.  "Prefetch" will load a resource in preparation for a navigation, while "preload" will load a resource on the currently navigated page before anything is rendered. More info one preload here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this warning is a bug

[as]- this attribute is used when rel="preload" or rel="prefetch" has been set on the  element.
It specifies the type of content being loaded/prefetched
Instead, 'preload' you can also use 'prefetch'

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="./img/intro.mp4" as="video">
```

So You can accomplish your task