# Preload image downloads multiple version of same image irrespective of media restrictions

Tags: html, preload, core-web-vitals

I have a banner which appears at the top fold of the page. To improve my LCP score, I am preloading the banner image to make it as a critical resource but I can see that for my mobile resolution, the tablet, mobile version of banner image is preloaded.

Please find below the markup of my banner image

```
`
            <picture><source srcset="mobile.jpg" media="(max-width: 767px)">
            
            
                <source srcset="tablet.jpg" media="(max-width: 1024px)">
            
            <!-- [if IE 9]></video><![endif] -->
            <img src="/desktop.jpg" width="1920" height="1080" alt="Kia Sportage">
        </picture>`
```

I am using below preloads to load images as per viewport sizes:

```
<link rel="preload" href="mobile.jpg" as="image" importance="high" media="(max-width: 767px)">
<link rel="preload" href="tablet.jpg" as="image" importance="high" media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)">
<link rel="preload" href="desktop.jpg" as="image" importance="high" media="(min-width: 1025px)">
```

For Tablet, Desktop size viewport I can see respective images getting preloaded but for mobile resolution I see that mobile.jpg and tablet.jpg is loaded and in console I can see Chrome complaining with below warning:

```
The resource tablet.jpg was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: With the question about Chrome, I've experienced errors in the console which are not real. With Firefox too. There might be a few more details about that if you Google it. I did manage to find the following question that might help with regard to `as-value`. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593084/link-rel-preload-must-have-a-valid-as-value

Comment: but I have added valid as="image" attribute to the tag.

Comment: I am not 100% sure about this but have you tried `as="img"`. I am really clutching at straws though.

Comment: as="img" is an invalid value. :(

Comment: Yeah I somehow thought that might be the case, sorry. Sit tight, more people will be looking as the day goes by.

Answer (score 2):

I found the cause!
Apparenntly The meta tag <meta name"viewport" content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> was defined way below in head tag in which case the viewport has not been configured when the media query is evaluated.