# Html video tag doesn't play in Safari within my Angular app

Tags: ios, angular, safari, html5-video

I am trying to play a video in my angular app, and it seems to work in every browser except with Safari :

```
<video controls autoplay muted class="media">
    <source src="https://my-site/files/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

I have seen this questions : [HTML5 Video tag not working in Safari , iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad#20347545), and it doesn't solve my problem.

At first, I had the problem with the byte range, I fixed it, and it still doesn't work.

If I put the video tag in an empty html webpage, the video plays, but in my angular app it still doesn't.

I used fiddler to get the http traces, and there are differences I don't understand.

When I have the  tag in an empty web page, I have the following request :

```
GET https://my-site/files/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: (my-site)
Accept-Encoding: identity
X-Playback-Session-Id: 14692D0E-A88B-4253-8B8A-BC580AB82174
Accept-Language: fr-fr
Range: bytes=0-1
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPod touch; CPU iPhone OS 12_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
Referer: (http://my-site/)
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

I can see several requests with different ranges, and the video plays.

But when I try to play the video from my Angular app, the request is different :

```
GET https://my-site/files/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: (my-site)
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPod touch; CPU iPhone OS 12_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
Accept-Language: fr-fr
Referer: (http://my-site/)
Accept-Encoding: br, gzip, deflate
```

This time there is no range header, so my server sends the whole file. And it doesnt play.

I have no idea what can cause this difference. The url of the video is the same (although the html webpage is on a different domain).

Comment: you sure it's not a autoplay bug ? Same bug with only `controls` as attribute ?

Comment: I can click on the 'play' button, but it still doesn't start the video

Comment: Hello, @glacasa i have same problem. you have got any solutions for this issue?

Comment: No, sorry :( we don't play the video for safari users...

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, still no solution, and I don't work on this project anymore...

Comment: Have you tried to add `playsinline` attribute? Also it's woth checking whether this is applied there is a chance that you need to make `attr.playsinline` or `attr.playsinline="1"` to tell angular that you are adding an attribute and not a prop.

Comment: Also have a look at https://medium.com/code-divoire/autoplaying-inline-videos-on-iphone-ios-10-using-angular-d4e2eaba2164

Comment: Also, maybe you could workaround it with programmatic `click()` event in `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `playsinline` attribute?

```
<video controls autoplay playsinline muted class="media">
    <source src="https://my-site/files/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try `<iframe>`

Example:

```
<iframe title="vimeo-player" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/336853299" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Mp4 might need to be converted using h264 codec. Mp4 has different kind of codecs and Safari doesn't support all of them because license issue I think.
Code to convert in nodejs

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);


function convertFile(input, output, size) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Entering converting file: " + size);
    ffmpeg(input)
      .format("mp4")
      .videoCodec("libx264")
      .size(size)
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.log("Error in converting file");
        reject(err);
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log("Success in converting file");
        resolve(output);
      }).saveToFile(output);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was because it was in the assets folder, every other browser it worked fine via assets, but for whatever reason Safari didn't like it, so I had to host the video file elsewhere, in my case, Azure Storage.

So now code looks like this

```
<video class="px-5" controls autoplay="autoplay" loop>
  <source src="azure-link/video.m4v" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the videos.
</video>
```