# Video's are not playing on iphone

Tags: html, laravel

I placed a video tag on a website. But when I want to play the video the video is black.

The video is retreived by a route to a laravel application, which returns a 200 video/mp4 response. I know for sure that the file is in mp4 format. I tried to embedded a other video from a other website but I got the same result. The video does work on computer browsers chrome, firefox and edge. The problems only seens to play when a iphone of apple user with safari tries to watch the video.

```
<video class="news" controls muted type="video/mp4">
    <source src="https://domain/news/4/video/1>
</video>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video tag not working in Safari , iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad)

Comment: What version of iOS is the phone running on?

Comment: Does the audio track play? Does the video have the right length (in seconds)? You can stuff a lot of different video and audio codecs into an MP4 container: What are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson Wilson I use the most recent public version of ios.

Comment: @Quentin the video does nothing. The timeline also shows 0 seconds.