# How to Fix "HTML5 video not load/work with safari browser in Angular PWA after production build"

Tags: angular, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing an Angular PWA which uses HTML5 video tag in some components , video working fine with development mode but when i make an production build and run it in server HTML5 video not work for me in safari browser so is there any solution available for it ?

I m using Angular 7.3.6 and Angular service worker 7.2.10 versions.

I have referred below link for solution but it is not helpful for me :

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23447

Comment: There are some solution in the SO community site, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad). Since you have not provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. You may want to browse on some of those answers.