# background video won’t play on mobile

Tags: html

Background video, for my website, is not playing on iPhone:

```html
<video id="video">
    <source loop="true" id="vid" src="assets/img/watch.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Try adding `autoplay` to the video tag. (`<video id="video" autoplay> <source loop="true" id="vid" src="assets/img/watch.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video>`)

Comment: Hi ! Please also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51432655/4698373) and let us know if the `playsinline` or `playsInline` attribute does something.

Answer (score 1):

use muted and autoplay attribute in video tag

```
  <video id="video"  muted autoplay>
       <source loop="true" id="vid" 
            src="assets/img/watch.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```