# HTML video tag not working in iOS or iPadOS irrespective of any browser

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

```html
<div class="sparsh-video-gallery-container">
  <img class="playBtn" src="http://local-ub/static/version1635318690/frontend/Attindas/corporate/en_US/images/play.svg">
  <video preload="auto" id="videoId-7" class="video-player" width="300" height="200" poster="">
    <source src="http://local-ub/media/sparsh/video_gallery/I_Am_Attindas_Revised_1_.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

I am using a html video tag in my project and the video is available in all the browsers but it is coming as white space in my iPhone and iPad device irrespective of the browser. When I try to use embed instead of source the video is not working in any of the desktop or mobile devices

Comment: Does your MP4 work okay in Safari on desktop/Mac? The link is untestable (cannot check video details, eg: if the MP4 contains H264 video codec and AAC audio codec).  Download a tool called **MediaInfo** to check audio/video codec names and tell us.

Answer (score 1):

`playasinline`, `controls` and the right mime-type definition in video tags on iOS devices are [a must](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20347352/16288497)

If you got a video player showing but it doesn't play the video, check if the server is [serving the content right](https://blog.logrocket.com/streaming-video-in-safari/), as iOS is very concious about how it is getting data over its data connection.