# Video stored in Firebase not playing in Iphones

Tags: html, django, firebase

I have a 5 Mb .mp4 video in firebase storage, using the below code it loads well in all web browsers. However it does not load in iPhone. .mp4s didn't work in safari but .mov did. However both .mp4 and .mov do not work on an iPhone. What can I do or video format to use?

```
<video width='100%' height='315' poster='{{ value.image }}' controls loop muted playsinline>
     <source type='video/mp4' src='{{ value.video }}'>
</video>
```

Comment: Check if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 Video tag not working in Safari , iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad)