# HTML video is not playing on IOS device

Tags: html

```
<video allowsInlineMediaPlayback playsinline autoplay loop muted>
            <source src="./src/video/CollabLens Bg video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
```

This html video is working fine on android devices on all browsers, but not working on IOS devices
not sure what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `controls=true` to the video tag.

You also have a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad) about `video` not working in IOS.

Comment: but i don't want controls

Comment: Oh okay, sorry. Check the thread, they should be able to help more than my suggestion then!