# html video tag sound not working | Safari İOS Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, safari, html5-video

HTML video tag audio not working in safari, what could be the reason?

```
<video id="vid" width="100%" height="1000" data-loop="true" playsinline autoplay muted preload="metadata" data-fill-mode="fill" class="ms-slide-bgvideo">
     <source src="image/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

js control

```
$('.video .icon .on').click(function(){
    $('video').prop('muted', true);
})

$('.video .icon .off').click(function(){
    $('video').prop('muted', false);
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 Video tag not working in Safari , iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad)

Comment: no my problem is related to sound

Comment: According to the MDN Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#browser_compatibility `muted` is not compatible with `safari` on `iOS`

Comment: Have you tried to use WebM extension file unlike mp4 because it's highly compatible with modern browser and popular for HTML5

Comment: When I make the video extension webm, the video does not appear on mobile at all

Comment: @BadPiggie on that page I see muted as compatible.