# Safari video issue

Tags: html, safari, html5-video

I want to add video on my website using html tag video. It works in chrome and other browsers except Safari. Video format (webM - for chrome and other browsers , mov - for safari).

```html
         <video class="animation-video" width="100%" height="130%" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
          <source src="video-path.mov" type="video/quicktime" />
          <source src="video-path.webm" type="video/webm" />
 </video>
```

Also i tried to display video in the tag video not in source.

```html
<video class="animation-video" width="100%" height="130%" autoplay loop muted playsinline src="path-video.mov">
          
 </video>
```

Anyway my video doesnt even displays in safari browser. Not even video playback icon.  I tried all possible solutions in this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad).
Unfortunately non of them helped..

**UPDATE** : My video is displaying now but it doesnt play
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfr10.png)
What is it or is it related to?