# Streaming to video tag on IOS

Tags: c#, html, ios, asp.net, backend

I have the following video tag:

`<Video autoplay controls id="player" src="">Your broswer does not support video tags</Video>`
The source is my .net core minimal webapi which returns a video using the following code:

`return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes($"Clips/{id}.mp4"), "application/octet-stream", $"{id}.mp4", enableRangeProcessing: true);` 
The video is streamed perfectly on windows, linux, android, anything under the sun essentially. However, on Apple devices it instead shows a play button with a slash through it.

I've tried adding the `playsinline` attribute to the video tag, to no avail.
Tried most answers from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad) which has made me question whether this may be an issue with the way my server returns the video. If so, are there any edits I need to make to the backend to make the video play on IOS?