# HTML5 video tag not loading on iPad

Tags: html, ipad, video, h.264

I'm trying to embed a video using the HTML5 video tag. It seems to work in all desktop browsers but apparently it's not working on iPad. Here's what I have:

```
<video width="352" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
    <source src="ytzeyoy2.webm" type='video/webm'/>
    <source src="y0lr4gep.ogv" type='video/ogg'/>
    <source src="1e-mvpwv.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
</video>
```

The videos all play in VLC. The .MP4 is h264 which as I understand should work on iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently its a MimeType issue Check this [link](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html) for more information

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511006/html5-video-not-working-on-ipad)

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

Its a mimetype issue

refer the links : http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html

http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#video-mime-types