# Video not playing on iPad using HTML5

Tags: ios, html, web, html5-video

I have following HTML code that is working fine for window PC and iPhone 4 with iOS version 7.1.2.

```
<video id="v1" width="640" height="480" controls>
<source scr="/videos/test.mp4"/>
</video>
```

but when I try to play this on my iPad 2, it does not play. iPad has version 8.2. it shows play button in the center with cross on it. then I try same file with .3gp, .ogv, .webm formats. the cross sign disappeared but video is still not playing.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511006/html5-video-not-working-on-ipad

Comment: @KK I tried that thread but no success. it is working fine with iPhone

Comment: I checked the headers from web server, and content-range header was there.

Comment: Did you looked for similar posts on stackoverflow?

Comment: I think there is some problem with the ipad. as I borrow an other ipad and this page is working fine on that one, video is also playing fine. I manually copied mp4 file on ipad file system, and it did not play it even with its own player.