# Html 5 video is not playing on iphone, ipad

Tags: php, html

I play a video on a website. Video is playing well on website but not play on iphone or ipad. its showing error html5 video is not supported.

i use this code..

```
<video id="example_video_1_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" preload="none" poster="http://www.xyz.com.au/media/videos/screen_stove.jpg" data-setup="{}" src="http://www.xyz.com.au/media/videos/stovetop.webm">
                <source src="http://www.xyz.com.au/media/videos/stovetop.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="http://www.xyz.com.au/media/videos/stovetop.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        <source src="http://www.xyz.com.au/media/videos/stovetop.mp4" type="video/mp4">

        <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
      </video>
```

what's wrong in my code..

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10511006/3282633) one ?

Comment: no i use simple html5 video code not any .js file..

Comment: Try this:<video controls>
 <source src="../videos/example.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <p>Your browser does not support H.264/MP4.</p>
</video>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opps mobile browser is not update may be so that i face this problem.

Now its working fine..

Thanks..

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to play HTML5 video on iPhone or iPad like on desktop browser. Flash player is not solution becouse Apple devices do not support it.

In pleace of movie try add an video poster. When user will click it then open movie in vimeo or youtube player popup.